# Does a JVM may be a limit to the IO transfer rate?

Tags: java, shell, jvm

I wonder if the JVM have an impact on hard disk writing/reading  ?

I know that the JVM can control the allocated heap memory for a process. For exemple, in shell I do this to set the allocated heap memory :

```
java -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -jar my_java_program.jar
```

So, Is it possible to set max or min speed of writing/reading on Hard Disk (IO) ?

Thank

**Edit :**

I've done a java program that constently writes text files. My program have the following architecture :

```
public class Generator {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

         // Variables initialization ...

         // Loading in RAM some data to generate my text files

         while(true){

               // Writing the file
               BufferedOutputStream buff = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(temporaryFolderPath, fileName)), 51200000);
               buff.write((some stuff ...).getBytes());
               buff.flush();
               buff.close();
         }
    }
}
```

I generate an executable JAR of this program and I execute this on a Virtual Machine with 8 CPU. My aim is to see the writing speed of this program, that's why, I've used the iostat command to check the IO disk tranfer.

The result with one instance :

wsec/s : around 8000

with wsec/s : The number of sectors written to the hard disk per second (I don't know the size of a sector)

The result with 2 instances :

wsec/s : around 16000

The result with 3 instances :

wsec/s : 32000

My question :

Why my writting is faster when I have several execution of instances of my java program ? Or What can limit this write speed for one instance ?

Comment: A JVM can certainly screw up IO rates, but it doesn't "control" them.

Answer (score 3):

No, whenever you use any of the Java libraries that read/write from disk, under the hood, Java is basically asking the O/S to deliver the data as fast as it can.

If you are experiencing a problem with slow I/O, then a common problem is forgetting to *buffer* data at the Java level. So for example, in general you should avoid using a FileInputStream directly, but instead wrap a BufferedInputStream around it. Buffer size will affect read/write speed (see e.g. [this graph of read time vs buffer size](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/io/input_stream_buffer_size.shtml)), but in general the default buffer sizes are good: the thing you need to do is remember to buffer in the first place.

Beyond that, to give a more satisfactory answer, we would really need to see what I/O performance you are having under what circumstances.

Comment: Thank for reply! I already use a Buffer to write my data. I've edited my question describing my problem. Maybe, you will have a clue to help me to understand.